# How do I get the assembler output from a C file in VS2005

Tags: c, visual-studio, assembly

I think the file that is produced is an .asm file, any idea how to produce this in Visual Studio when you do a build?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Open the Properties page for a project
2. Select the `Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Output Files` branch
3. Change the Assembler Output option to something other than `No Listing`
4. Make sure ASM List Location is set to a valid path or sub-path
5. Build.

Comment: Don't forget to turn off /GL option (Whole program optimization). Otherwise, asm file will not be created. It happens in the case of Release configuration.

Answer (score 5):

Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Output Files

There you should see an option for Assembler Output.

John.

Answer (score 2):

Or if using the Visual Studio command line,

cl.exe /Fa[assembler code filename]

If you just want to view the assembler code in the IDE you can start the debugger and then select the Go To Dissassembly choice on the right click menu.