# Visual Studio equivalent to gcc -S

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the assembler output from a C file in VS2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34635/how-do-i-get-the-assembler-output-from-a-c-file-in-vs2005)

Is there a way to display assembly code generated from a translation unit in C/C++ in MS Visual Studio? I mean the same effect as gcc/g++ -S command in Linux. I know the "Show dissassembly" Menu but it's active only while debugging and it shows the assembler code of the whole project.

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020498/how-to-view-the-assembly-behind-the-code-msvc-if-relevent

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367y26c6.aspx

You can use 
"/FA  /Fa" options you can use..

In there documents, 

CL /FAcs HELLO.CPP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in **Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Output Files -> Assembler Output**.